# how can I make those tables into groups?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

So many tables in the fields[/field tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUxvV.png), is there any methods to group them to folders, like the measure[/measure group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtMyF.png), and power query also can group tables[/power query group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MIwF.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such feature, but you can vote to implement it here:

[Group Tables in Report View](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=9267b1d4-cf7d-4c67-8c2f-54b5e3544457).

According to number of votes, it's not seen as super relevant by the users.
So, consider consolidating your tables and hide all the temporary ones from the view.

Comment: crying, anyway thank you, I haven't found related info in the internet before. Why power query has this basic funtion, and it need to be vote in powerbi desktop